# What does "Placed: ++" mean in manyland?

Tags: manyland

What does "Placed: ++" mean in manyland? Some of my friends have that and it is confusing me. It says "Placed 10k+" for me and I know what that means. I just need to know what the "++" means. It's been bugging me for a week.

Answer (score 2):

IT's how many things you placed. ++ = 1,000,000k

Comment: I heard from someone that is is 100k, so now I am really confused.

Answer (score 0):

Update: Manyland Now Makes it "++" after 10k placements, this is because people were spamming to get to ++

Comment: Shouldn't that number be higher then?

Comment: No they lowered it because they don't want people spamming 100k blocks to get to have ++ on their profile. now its less of an achievement and even if people spam to get 10k then its 90k less than it was before.

Answer (score -1):

yes its 100k+ blocks that is what I heard before

Comment: Welcome to the site! Do you have any links or other sources that support your answer?